# React Native - Function is not recognized inside Another Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Realtime Storage. I'm trying to call function from inside the firebase ref.on() function.

My code:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      dosomething(snapshot.val()) //<-- not recognized
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
   } 

  dosomething(val){
    //...
  }

  //....
});
```

I'm trying to make the `dosomething()` function to get called from the `ref.on()` function but React don't recognize the `dosomething()` function

Why is it happened recognize and How do I fix it?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to change `function (snapshot) {` to `(snapshot) => {`

now the `this` inside that callback is the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context - i.e the constructor

and then you can use `this.dosomething` - because `dosomething` is a property of `this`

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ref.on("value", (snapshot) => {
      this.dosomething(snapshot.val())
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
   } 

  dosomething(val){
    //...
  }

  //....
});
```